# Overcome Pending Promise and Finish Building JSON in Node.js with Axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, promise, axios

I'm trying to build a `JSON` file by making successive `HTTP requests` with `Axios`:

1. Get an array of objects (projects)
2. Create an array property in each project named tasks
3. Get each project's tasks
4. Push each project's tasks into its tasks property (i.e. populate that array in each project object)
5. Create a `JSON` file out of the modified projects array

Code:

```
let getProjects = function() {
  try {
    return axios.get('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/').then(response => { return response } )
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

let getTasks = function(project) {
  try {
    return axios.get('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/'+project+'/tasks').then(response => { return response } )
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}

function getAsanaData() {
  return getProjects()
    .then(function(result) {
      let projects = []
      for(let project of result.data.data){
        project.tasks = []
        project.tasks.push(getTasks(project.gid))
        projects.push(project)
      }
      return projects;
    })
}

Promise.try(() => {    
    return getAsanaData();
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(util.inspect(result, {showHidden: false, depth: null}))
    var asanaData = JSON.stringify(result);
    fs.writeFile("thing.json", asanaData);
});
```

The log result is something like this:

```
[ { id: 35534235917762,
    gid: '35534235917762',
    name: 'History+',
    resource_type: 'project',
    tasks: [ Promise { <pending> } ] },
  { id: 35583453238038,
    gid: '35583453238038',
    name: 'NRG - AccountingSeed Phase 2',
    resource_type: 'project',
    tasks: [ Promise { <pending> } ] },
]
```

Note the persistence of `Promise { <pending> }`.

The JSON is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 35534235917762,
    "gid": "35534235917762",
    "name": "History+",
    "resource_type": "project",
    "tasks": [
      {}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 35583453238038,
    "gid": "35583453238038",
    "name": "NRG - AccountingSeed Phase 2",
    "resource_type": "project",
    "tasks": [
      {}
    ]
  }
]
```

Note the empty tasks properties.

It seems I'm very close to achieving a complete `JSON`, but I've spent many hours trying to get past the pending `promise` and finally adding the missing data.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `getTasks` is asynchronous, so simply calling `getTasks` in a `for` loop won't wait for the Promises to resolve. To wait for all of them to resolve, use `Promise.all` on an array of those Promises, and then when *that* resolves, you can assign the result to `project.tasks`:

```
function getAsanaData() {
  return getProjects()
    .then((result) => {
      const projects = result.data.data;
      const taskPromises = projects.map((project) => {
        return getTasks(project.gid)
          .then((task) => {
            project.tasks = [task];
          });
      });
      return Promise.all(taskPromises)
        .then(() => projects);
  });
}
```

Also note that a rejected `Promise` won't be caught inside a `try` / `catch` block:

```js
try {
  new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(reject, 1000))
} catch(e) {
  console.log('error caught');
}
```

Instead of `try/catch`, the proper way to catch `Promise` errors (when you aren't using `await`) is to chain a `.catch` handler at the end of the `Promise` chain:

```
const getProjects = function() {
  return axios.get('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/')
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}
```

But `.catch` results in the `Promise` chain *resolving*, rather than rejecting, which means that when the function is called, the resulting `Promise` will *resolve to a value* (`undefined`) rather than rejecting, which probably isn't what you want - you might find the control flow easier to handle if you catch errors in the *caller* of the function instead:

```
return Promise.all(taskPromises)
  .then(() => projects);
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Something else to note is that a `.then` such as

```
.then(response => { return response } )
```

is completely superfluous - the existing `Promise` already resolves to the `response`. Chaining another `Promise` into the end which takes in the input and outputs it again doesn't do anything useful - feel free to leave that off completely.

Answer (score 0):

You could try async await syntax to write asynchronous code like synchronous using promises.
It could be simple to understand and follow the promise complete.
example:

We could overwrite your getProject function like this:

```
let getProjects = async function() {

   let projectsResponse;
   try {
     projectsResponse = 
        axios.get('https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/');
   } catch (error) {
      console.error(error)
   }

   return projectsResponse && projectsResponse.data || [];
}
```